# How to stay connected in an iOS webapp?

Tags: ios, logging, web-applications, session-cookies

I'm developing an iOS web app which require user logging.
Currently I'm storing the cookies in keychain when the application close or goes background and when the user reopen the app I load the data stored and write down the cookies.
But my problem is that I don't know how to reload the website to avoid that the user need to renter his credentials.

Here is what I do to load the cookies

```
func loadCookies(){
    print("loading")
    let url = URL(string: "mobi.kronos-sport.com")!
    let keychain = KeychainSwift()
    let data=keychain.allKeys
    for key in data {
        let value = keychain.get(key)!
        var dayComponent    = DateComponents()
        dayComponent.day=21
        let theCalendar     = Calendar.current
        let nextDate        = theCalendar.date(byAdding: dayComponent, to: Date())

        print("k \(key) v \(value)")
        let httpCookie = HTTPCookie.init(properties:
            [HTTPCookiePropertyKey.version : "0",
             HTTPCookiePropertyKey.name : key,
             HTTPCookiePropertyKey.path : "/",
             HTTPCookiePropertyKey.value : value,
             HTTPCookiePropertyKey.expires : nextDate])
        if let cookie = httpCookie {
            HTTPCookieStorage.shared.setCookie(cookie)
        }
    }
}
```

The console log shows that it founds the correct pairs key/value

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is a server side configuration preventing restoring session (cookie cookie secure)